# retrieve data contained in two foreign tables referenced in single table by pivot table with eloquent

Tags: join, eloquent, pivot

Maybe with this image I can make myself clear.
I have the `user table` and the `owned_items table`
The owned items are attached to the user by the `users_owned_item` pivot table

by using this eloquent method

```
$owned_items = Auth::user()->owned_items->toArray();
```

what I get are "**item_type_id**" and "**item_color_id**" contained in the `owned_items` table.
What I really need though is the actual data contained in the `item_types` and `item_colors` tables, the question is: how do I get that data instead of the foreign keys id?

**p.s. the varchar type of "item_id" in user_owned_items table is only an error, it's an INT of course.**

Also please let me know if these relationship are correct:

in the **User model**

```
public function owned_items(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\owned_items')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

in the **owned_items** model

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

public function Item_type(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Item_type');

    }

public function Item_color(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Item_color');

    }
```

In the **Item_type** model

```
public function Owned_item(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Owned_item');
    }
```

In the **Item_color** model

```
public function Owned_item(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Owned_item');
        }
```

[image: data in foreign tables]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, given the models structure I described. This way I can access the data. Please let me know if there's a different easier way:

```
public function index()
    {

        $id = Auth::id();

        $user = User::find($id);

        $results = array();

        foreach ($user->owned_item as $i) {

            $results [] = array(

                "type" => $i->Item_type->type,
                "color" => $i->Item_color->color

        );

        }

        dd ($results);

    }
```

This, for example, results in:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "type" => "Type A"
    "color" => "black"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "type" => "Type B"
    "color" => "red"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "type" => "Type C"
    "color" => "green"
  ]
]
```

So I can pass this results to my view, is that correct? I can't think of any other method to create an array with the data I need. Does eloquent permit something better?